# What is the alternate for initialize method(apiController) in .net core(controllerBase)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am migrating an asp.net WebAPI application (inherited APIController) to .net core API application(inherited ControllerBase). I have a initialize method with parameter System.web.http.controllers.HttpControllerContext.

What is the alternative to initialize method which performs the same functionality?

Comment: Please add more specifics to your post and what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with ASP.NET WebAPI, but in my .NET Core WebAPI projects, I just use the controller's constructor and the built-in dependency injection functionality for initializing my controllers.

In your case for accessing `HttpContext`, you might try the following:

In `Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        //...
    }
}
```

With this, you should be able to use the `Controller` class' `HttpContext` property inside your controller methods:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class DummyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessMyDummyPostAction()
    {
        //...

        HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Request;

        //...

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should instead of accessing ```HttpContext``` directly use ```IHttpContextAccessor```. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1)